# Golang prepend the array

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var result [][]int
    var tempArr []int
    tempArr = append(tempArr, 1, 2, 3, 5)
    result = append(result, tempArr)
    prepend := []int{1, 2, 3}
    result = append([]int{prepend}, result...) // Not working
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

What is the correct way to prepend to an array? I need help to fix this line:

```
result = append([]int{prepend}, result...)
```

Comment: Following [push front](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#push-frontunshift) in the slice tricks wiki, the code should be:  `result = append([][]int{prepend}, result...)`

Comment: I got this working by doing this ```result = append([][]int{prepend}, result...) ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is mismatch. `[]int{prepend}` type is `[] int`. But `prepend` type is `[] int`. So `[]int{prepend}` is not correct. The right way is `[][]int{prepend}`, below code will pass.

```
result = append([][]int{prepend}, result...)
```

The result will be:

```
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 5]]
```